# How to make Matlab do lazy evaluation?

Tags: matlab, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to do the following integral numerically.

```
b = 2;
f1 = @(x) (b<1).*x./(2-b);
R = integral(f1,0,1);
```

This code gives me `R=NaN`. I understand that Matlab probably evaluates `x./(2-b)` and finds there is a 0 at the bottom of the fraction, which immediately generates a `NaN`. Then, all of the subsequent operations are ruined by this `NaN`.

What I want is: Matlab does the operations from the left to the right, i.e., first check `b<1`. If `b<1` is violated, then it stops to evaluate the next thing in the bracket (which avoids getting `NaN`).

I am not sure how to achieve this goal, or if Matlab is capable of doing that.

My actual computation is very complicated that involves tons of this type of logical comparisons. Any comments and suggestions are highly appreciated!

Comment: You could always just add a tiny epsilon to the denominator so that it is never exactly 0. That is as lazy (albeit imperfect) a solution as I can think of.

Comment: The `&&` operator does short-circuiting, but it always yields a boolean. What  you are looking for is a function `if b < 1, f = x./(2-b); else, f = 0; end`. You cannot write this in an anonymous function, you will have to write a regular function for this. Actually, there is a way to do this in an anonymous function, but it complicated, ugly, and inefficient. You are much better off writing a regular function.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  I see... thank you!

Comment: @dmedine thank you!  My current way of doing it is `f1 = @(x) (b<1).*x./(2-b.*(b<1));` It works for this case, but not something widely applicable, I think...